# 0x80040119 Error while sending email

Tags: gmail, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am trying to configure my mailboxes on Outlook 2013 on my new laptop. My local Exchange mail box is configured OK and I am able to send and receive mail with it.

When I try to add my Gmail's IMAP mailbox, the Add account wizard is completes the Test Account settings with successful sending of Outlook test mail. Incoming mail too works fine. But when I try to send an email, the mail stays in the Outbox itself and Send/Receive reports the following error:

> Task '___@mspvl.com - Sending' reported error (0x80040119) : 'Unknown Error 0x80040119'

What could be wrong?

The settings I used to configure Gmail:

```
Account Type : IMAP
Incoming mail server: imap.gmail.com
Outgoing mail server: smtp.gmail.com
Require Logon using SPA [] (Not Checked)
My outgoing Server SMTP requires authentication : Checked
Same Settings as incoming mail server.

Port Numbers : IMAP : 993 : SSL
SMTP: 465 : SSL
```

Version Information:

Microsoft Outlook 2013 15.0.4569.1503 MSO (15.0.4569.1506) 32 Bit
Windows 8.1 Single Language Edition

Answer (score 0):

#### 0x80040119 Error while sending email

You should run the Inbox Repair Tool `scanpst`.

---

#### "An unknown error has occurred" error message in Outlook

> **Symptoms**
>
> In Microsoft Outlook, you may receive one of the following error
>   messages when you try to read, send, receive, or delete an email
>   message.
>
> Error message 1: "An unknown error has occurred. 0x80040119"
>
> Error message 2: "An unknown error has occurred. 0x80040600"
>
> Or, when you try to delete email messages, you may receive the
>   following error message: "Messaging interface has caused an unknown error"
>
> **Resolution**
>
> The error may be caused by a corrupted Outlook Data File (*.pst) in
>   the Outlook profile.
>
> To repair the corrupted file, follow these steps.
>
> Step 1: Locate the default *.pst file that is using the Outlook
>   profile
>
> - In Control Panel, open the Mail the item.
> - Click Show Profiles. Select the Outlook profile that experiences the issue, and then click Properties.
> - Click Data files.
> - Make a note of the location of the default *.pst file. The name of the default *.pst file contains a black circle with a check mark.
>
> [image]
>
> Step 2: Run the Outlook Inbox Repair Tool (SCANPST.exe) to repair the
>   *.pst file
>
> - Exit Outlook.
> - Open the Outlook Inbox Repair Tool (SCANPST.exe).
> - In the Enter the name of the file you want to scan box, type the location of the *.pst file.
> - Click Start.
>
> Where to find the Outlook Inbox Repair Tool
>
> Outlook 2013
>
> - 32-bit version of Windows: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\`
> - 64-bit version of Windows: `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\`
> - 64-bit Outlook: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\`
>
> ...
>
> **More information**
>
> If the methods that are described in the "Resolution" section don't
>   resolve the problem, you can try creating a new Unicode .pst file,
>   setting it as the default, and then importing the data from your older
>   .pst file.

Source ["An unknown error has occurred" error message in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814441)